# Ruby and WS-Security

Tags: ruby, soap, ws-security

I'm having troubles finding good Ruby libraries that implement WS-Security. I've seen [wss4r](http://rubyforge.org/projects/wss4r/) but have yet to use it (and the documentation is a bit light on it). What libraries do you use for this task, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with soap much myself, but this ruby extension is on my list of things to try: [here](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/ruby).  Might want to check it out.